# Does Kotlin `by` keyword work for nullable delegate?

Tags: android, kotlin, delegation

I've pretty excited by Kotlin compiler features and by `by` in particular - it saves time generating gelegating code:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

But i want delegate to be **nullable** and delegating code to check if it's null first and return if it is:

```
interface Base {
    val message: String
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int?) : Base {
    override val message = "BaseImpl: x = $x"
    override fun print() { println(message) }
}

class Derived(b: Base?) : Base by b {
    // This property is not accessed from b's implementation of `print`
    override val message = "Message of Derived"
}

fun main() {
    val b = BaseImpl(10)
    val derived = Derived(b)
    derived.print()
    println(derived.message)
}
```

When compiling ^ i'm getting `Type mismatch: inferred type is Base? but Base was expected`.

Is it still possible with Kotlin?

To be more detailed i'd like Kotlin compiler to generate forwarding calls to wrapped impl (`extWebChromeClient`) in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient like follows:

```
private WebChromeClient intWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient()
  {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title)
    {
      if (extWebChromeClient != null)
      {
        extWebChromeClient.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
      }
    }
 ...
```

Comment: Whether or not this is possible, I find it unreasonable. It would work only on `void` methods anyway.

Comment: Operator `?.` works on non-void methods by making the return type nullable. This cannot possibly work here, because it would violate the contract of `Base`. In theory there is nothing preventing it from working on interfaces where all methods already return nullable type.

Comment: @Marko i find it reasonable. Methods that return value can be required for overriding. Anyway it saves lot's of time to write boilerplate code.

Comment: You couldn't delegate `WebChromeClient` anyway because it's a class, not an interface.

Comment: Actually, since `WebChromeClient` is not abstract and its callbacks do nothing by default, why not just make `extWebChromeClient` non-nullable in the first place and initialize/set it to `WebChromeClient()` instead of `null`? No need to generate any code.

Comment: If "null-checked delegation" is supported by Kotlin compiler i'd prefer to use it. Otherwise it can work as a [not perfect] workaround as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this yourself using [dynamic proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), though I wouldn't really recommend it. Note that for non-`void` methods there's no way to require overriding them. The below implementation just throws exceptions for them unconditionally, but you could still call them for non-null `x`.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> nullableProxy(x: T?): T {
    val handler = InvocationHandler { _, method, args ->
        if (method.returnType == Void.TYPE) {
            if (x != null) {
                method.invoke(x, *(args ?: arrayOf()))
            }
        } else 
            throw UnsupportedOperationException("Non-void method")
    }

    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        T::class.java.classLoader,
        arrayOf(T::class.java),
        handler) as T
}

class Derived(b: Base?) : Base by nullableProxy(b)
```

This also won't perform as well as implementing methods directly would.

Comment: this will make it too slow imho

Comment: @4ntoine Slower? Yes, as mentioned in the answer. Whether it's too slow depends on a specific situation. The alternative is code generation. Just in case: when you say it saves a lot of time to write boilerplate code, you do realize how to write code only once per `Base` interface, not once per `Derived` class?

Comment: i've meant reflection call is significantly slower than direct one (code generated by kotlin compiler) so the main performance drop is because of this and not because of "specific situation". I've used dynamic proxies in JSON-RPC lib and i've measure performance drop. Also your code can throw `InvocationTargetException` instead of original exception and it makes sense: one should rethrow original exception cause instead.